# Can't install Realm library via CocoaPods in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift2, realm, cocoapods

I am making iOS app in Swift2.0.

I tried to install Realm library via CocoaPod.

It is fine when I execute 'pod install' in command line.

But in Xcode project, I can't build my iOS app.

There is an error and stop to build.

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: can't open file: /Users/satoutakeshi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlermMA-hczduhcpoaudvlgzjrzioeecipfh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlermMA.app/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Realm (No such file or directory)
```

It's my Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'RealmSwift'
```

What should I do to install Realm?

Thanks!

Comment: My iOS project is  combination of Swift and Objective-C.

Comment: Which version of CocoaPods do you use?

Comment: 0.38.2 version I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be seeing this error because using the `RealmSwift` pod is not supported in mixed Objective-C/Swift Apps. Try using the Objective-C Realm pod:

```
pod 'Realm'
```

You'll still be able to use Realm in your Swift files, you'll just have to convert the Objective-C syntax to Swift and, of course, the Swift only stuff in `RealmSwift` won't be available.

Comment: Thank your answer! I tried to  `pod 'Realm'`  and it's works good.

Answer (score 1):

If your project was in Swift you you would have to install `RealmSwift` to use the full swift features:

```
pod 'RealmSwift'
```

In your code you have to import both Realm and RealmSwift to use all features:

```
import Realm
import RealmSwift
```

**EDIT:**

I updated this answer. Thanks to [Donamite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/881250/donamite) for pointing out that you only need to have `RealmSwift' in the podfile.

Comment: Having only `pod 'RealmSwift'` is sufficient, as the `Realm` pod is a dependency of that pod, and in fact having both in your Podfile may cause issues, if, for example, `RealmSwift` is ever dependent on a different version than you have specified in your Podfile.  I.e., don't do this :)

Comment: You don't have to import both frameworks. I'd even discourage from doing that, because it can led to confusion. It's sufficient to `import RealmSwift`.

Comment: That's why I thought, however when you want to work with `RLMRealmConfiguration` you get a compiler error if you only import RealmSwift. It also wants `import Realm`